Logging Exceptions and events in a Spring Boot application running as a Windows service
I'm running a Spring Boot backend application as a Windows service, and I'm seeking a method to monitor logs for all exceptions and events in real-time. However, I haven't found a suitable solution yet. Since I need to track events as they occur, relying on file logs is not feasible.
I've been suggested using tools like Logstash, but I'm not sure about this approach.
